# "jquery-Target has no method .css()"

Tags: javascript, css, events, background, target

I'm trying to get the CSS background-color of a div-element I'm clicking on. Now I've tried this (don't think that it needs more code):

```
...
    var onColorClicked = function(color) {
    var $target = (color.target);

    console.log($target.innerHTML);
    console.log($target.css('background'));

}, ....
```

So, the first log is printing the content correct, without an error, but the second log says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object # has **no method 'css'**

As I see it, the $target is containing the right target, but it's still having problems.
That's the CSS I've defined before:

```
            $color.css({
                left: 64,
                top: (i*10)-188,
                "z-index": 80,
                'background': "#e40613"     
            });
```

What's the problem with .css() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
// mind the -> 
var $target = $(color.target);

console.log($target.html());
console.log($target.css('background'));
```

Just as a sidenote, variables in javascript don't need to start with a `$`, so it can be `target` instead of `$target`.

Comment: It's (relatively) common to use a `$` to indicate jQuery-ized objects, though.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ True, I've found myself doing it a few times as well, but was unsure if the OP is aware.

Comment: Thank you, the $ before (color.target) was missing. Then it works just with html(). But to get the backgroundcolor, the parameter must be: $target.css('background-color'). That works!